# How to programmatically eliminate space occupied by SearchView hint icon in SearchView

Tags: java, android, searchview, android-search

I'm trying to programmatically remove space that the icon within the SearchView hint takes up, but for some reason it won't go away.

This code makes the icon invisible, but it doesn't remove the space:

```
    try {
        Field mDrawable = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchHintIcon");
        mDrawable.setAccessible(true);
        Drawable drawable =  (Drawable)mDrawable.get(searchView);
        drawable.setAlpha(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: try android:gravity="left" and android:textAlignment="gravity" in xml

Comment: You want to remove the magnifying glass from the searchview?

Comment: @forpas From the hint, programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
drawable.setBounds(0,0,0,0);
```

to your code because the drawable is still there even if it is invisible